# How to create a text-only favicon?

Tags: html, favicon

Is there a free and easy text-only favicon generator? There are numerous online favicon generators asking for a image+text to create a favicon. I am interested in putting only text into my favicon, probably with a choice of different fonts. Anybody knows of a a good online text-only favicon generator?

Also, any desktop solution that does not involve paid software will also do. Does anybody know of such an option (I use a MAC)?

Comment: This may be the dumbest question of the night, but do you mean actually text only, or am image of text? I ask because my limited understanding of .ico files is that they are, well, icon files and thus always an image. Is that not the case?

Comment: In all probability, Shreeni, you use a Mac, not a MAC.

Comment: @Anthony: I understand that a favicon is always an image. I am looking to generate it without having to play around with images myself. Not everybody wants to be playing in photoshop. 

@Chris Lutz: Is stackoverflow also heading away from technical issues into trivial details? I did mean Mac and not a MAC. So sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know a good online one, but why not just boot up MacPaint and put some black text on a white background?  You could save the result as an image in the right size yourself, or upload it to one of the generators to get the sizing and formatting done for you.  Your font choice would be quite large, as you could use any of the free fonts available on the web.

Comment: @karl @zombat: Thanks to both of you. I am getting a free paint-like software, creating either the background to use with one of the online ones, or making it end to end myself. It seems quite a common case to me that one of the online generators should support it, but alas thats not the case I believe.

Answer (score 11):

A simple only solution is http://antifavicon.com/

Not the prettiest favicons, but very simple, with a retro look ;)

Answer (score 4):

I have found one site which exactly does what you want, the site address is https://favicon.io/. (see the image below)
[image]

It can generate 16X16 and 32x32 favicon image. It can also generate a 1024x1024 png image. You can use [this site](https://www.favicon-generator.org/) to generate various favicon from the big image.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.animatedfavicon.com

With this one you can generate an animated gif of a scrolling text (and an icon).
It's very easy to use.
Rename the gif to favicon.ico and put it in the root folder of your webpage.

For the "no icon" part. Simply use a 16px white gif as "icon"

[alt text http://www.animatedfavicon.com/iconz/5d7acd6919b25b7651ee9bd9fefbbb69_extra_animated_favicon.gif](http://www.animatedfavicon.com/iconz/5d7acd6919b25b7651ee9bd9fefbbb69_extra_animated_favicon.gif)

Comment: Animated favicons are so irritating! Why distract your users from your website? (I'm sure they can be done well but just aren't)

Comment: @edeverett: Agreed. I was looking for one which could make quick favicons based on single character (say "S"), font and color of the text and background. Animated is not what I am looking for.

Comment: @The Disintegrator: Thats the whole point. For a quick favicon, I don't want to bother myself with having to upload a image. I want to try out quite a few "text" favicons with different background, resolution, font, text and text color. With the approach you are mentioning, I would have to create multiple background files. For all that effort, I might as well do it myself in Photoshop/MacPaint etc.

Answer (score 2):

http://faviconist.com/

It has nice font collection and simple color scheme.

> Faviconist is a Favicon generator with a difference: No need for image
>   uploading or editing. Just provide a letter (or another character) and
>   a color scheme, and we'll make the icon for you. Click "Save Favicon"
>   to keep it.

Comment: site is not reachable

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would just boot up some image editor and make a 16x16 png image, then use the png image as the favicon. It doesn't have to be an ico file, and even if it does just convert it using something (I don't know what software would do this on a mac, gimp maybe?)

No matter what it's going to be an image, but if you want the image to just be a letter or something you can do that.

Comment: I think it needs to be a .ico file for IE (at least IE6 - not sure about 7 and 8)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easiest way:

1. Open up Microsoft's Paint.
2. Type the texts you want.
3. From Paint's menu, "Resize" by "Pixels" to 16x16.
4. Save image as .png to get a clear background.
5. Go to http://www.favicon-generator.org/
6. Follow favicon-generator instruction accordingly.
7. Done!

Comment: If you use this method to resize it will just crop the image leaving only the top left 16x16 pixels

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the favicon on a webpage, you could generate a text favicon on the fly in your page.  Here is how I have done that.  They way I have done it is you have to give the favicon link an "id", then generate a canvas filled with colors and text.

Here is a sample webpage, showing the link with the id, the javascript function, and the javascript function being called.  You may have to fiddle with the x and y coordinates and font size to get the text centered in the favicon.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--  Need this link in the head -->
    <link id="favicon-link" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="">
    <!--------------------------------->
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>You document here</p>
    <script>
        //The function to make the favicon.
        function makeFavicon(letters, color, backgroundColor, fontSizeInPixels, x, y) {
            //put this in head of html document
            //<link id="favicon-link" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="">
            let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = 16;
            canvas.height = 16;

            let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 16, 16);

            let ctx2 = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx2.fillStyle = color;
            ctx2.font = "bold "+fontSizeInPixels.toString()+"px Arial";
            ctx2.fillText(letters, x, y);

            let link = document.getElementById("favicon-link");
            link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/x-icon");
        }
        //Call the function to make the favicon
        makeFavicon("Yo", "white", "blue", 12, 1, 12);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ideas influenced by:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/906658/bengt,
[How to create a favicon in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809144/how-to-create-a-favicon-in-javascript)