# How to create a favicon in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, favicon

I want to add a [favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) to a website to be able to identify it's tab. I do not want the favicon to be a file, though. What is the best way to create one in Javascript?

Reasons

- A favicon file requires an additional HTTP request which increases the page load time.
- Changing the web server might change static content serving to another fashion, which causes headaches.

PS: I have presented [a solution as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12809146/906658) to this, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If simple, form based graphics suffice, one can use HTML5 Canvas to create a favicon. There have been successful attempts to [modify a favicon image after loading it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6964230/906658). Analogously one can create a favicon entirely in javascript using the basic canvas API. The following example creates and sets a grey favicon with a green square on it:

```
<script>
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 16;
    canvas.height = 16;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = "#aaa";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 16, 16);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#afa";
    ctx.fillRect(4, 4, 8, 8);            
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.type = 'image/x-icon';
    link.rel = 'shortcut icon';
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/x-icon");
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
</script>
```

For currently outdated versions Internet Explorer (<9) one needs a workaround like [Explorer Canvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/). See the [official instructions](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/wiki/Instructions) on how to do that.

Comment: @jrd1: Yes, it's called sharing knowledge. Check the ["Ask Question"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page.

Comment: @Deadalus: I asked for the best way to do this. This solution only works for simple graphics and IE>=9. I extended/clarified my question and answer.

Comment: @bngtlrs, agreed. I meant no offense by it. When I posted that, you hadn't updated your question to reflect your answer. Hence, my incredulous comment.

Comment: @jrd, none taken. I did this "Q&A at once" before and irritated people by it, but sometimes it seems the right tool for collecting knowledge. Perhaps I should be more cautious to clarify what I do and want by it